Can I power a 12v pea bulb with a 9v battery?
I am trying to power some dolls house lighting. It is essentially a series of 3 x 12v pea bulbs. I have found that they work with two AA batteries (1.5v) but only lasts for about 3 hours. Would a 9v PP3 battery last longer? And if so, how long?
Thanks

The data sets should give an idea of the energy contained in both batteries. What about using small LEDs?

why don't you test the 9 V battery to see how long it lasts?

No, it would be much brighter but would last much less time. A primary alkaline AA cell of good quality might be 2000-3000mAh. A 9V alkaline battery will be much less, maybe 600mAh. And the lamp will draw much more current at the 3x higher voltage (not 3x which is proportionally more, but much more). Even if you put them in series rather than parallel they would be similarly bright but the battery would last somewhat less time.
I suggest a 5V AC adapter if you want it to be reasonably bright and not eat batteries. Or use rechargeable batteries.
You can also buy small LEDs (even 0402) with wires attached, which will be more efficient (photo just for illustration- no connection with this seller and I have not used them- recommended to shop around, it should be carried by other marketing platforms and other sellers)
The LEDs are more directional though, so may not be suitable for some applications.

You need to add resistors to the LEDs, but the resistors can be hidden somewhere. You could also put a couple LEDs in series with one resistor if you are using 9V.
